# How to check if vector of string is balanced?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following algorithm than check if string is balanced

```
bool IsBalanced(string input)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '(') count++;
        if (input[i] == ')') count--;
        if (count < 0) return false;
    }
    if (count == 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

How to use this method to check if `vector<string>` is balanced?

```
vector<string> VectorOfBalanced(vector<string> values) 
{
}
```

Sample Input:

```
values = { "{}[]()", "{[}]}" }
```

Sample Output

```
return = { "YES", "NO" }`
```

Comment: Use a loop and check each string in the vector?

Comment: the algorithm is supposed to check the balance of only round brackets `(, )`  or of all type of brackets? Because running it on the second string you would get `"YES"`.

Comment: @svs just this {[(

Comment: @Anatoly well, then this algorithm is not correct.

Comment: Can you help me to create more correct algorithm please?

Comment: Hint: Is the string `{([})]` balanced?

Comment: A clue: use stack data structure.

Comment: Stackoverflow is loosing quality, having a question like this with that many votes.

Comment: using stack is your answer.

Comment: stackoverflow is indeed on a downward curve, but not because of a question like this one. It's the clueless parade that post either completely unrelated, isolated, snippets of code, or "please write my C0de3 for me". So, when a question with a [mcve] comes up, even if it's a simple one like this one, it's a breath of fresh air and the natural reaction is to upvote.

Comment: The code in this question is plagiarised from https://yadiragarnica.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/parentheses-algorithms/. OP has made no attempt to solve the problem himself, and is only looking for others to do his work.

Comment: @interjay good catch. I am voting to close this question

Answer (score 3):

> How to use this method to check if vector is balanced?

you can use regular for loop, but in c++ we have more general algorithms like std::transform.

I assume your question is not whether IsBalanced is correct but how to apply it to vector of strings.

```
vector<string> res;
std::transform(
    values.begin(), values.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(res), 
    [](auto& s) -> auto { return IsBalanced(s) ? "Yes" : "No"; });
```

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about how to apply it to vector of strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a two parter: how to check if the string is balanced with respect to multiple sets of opening/closing characters, like "()", "{}", and "[]", and then how to extend this to a vector of strings.

The latter part is easy: just repeat the algorithm for each string in the vector.

For the former part, you need to keep track of the list of all outstanding opening characters, in a stack of some kind. A `std::vector<char>` would be an excellent choice:

1. Initialize the stack to empty.
2. Iterate over each character in the string to check.
3. If the character is one of the opening characters, like '(', '[', or '{', push it onto the stack.
4. If the character is one of the closing characters, like ')', ']', or '}', then: if and only if the stack is non-empty and the character at the end of the stack is a matching opening character, then pop it from the stack and proceed with your iteration. Otherwise, the string is not balanced.
5. If, after finishing iteration the stack is not empty, the string is not balanced.

You should be able to trivially translate the above into C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide path for you more than an actual answer. You need to look up for `std::stack`and the simple way to do it is that every time you see an open ones `{ [ (` you do `YourStackName.push()` and once you see a closed ones you do `YourStackName.pop()`. You need however to maintain your logic (don't pull if it is empty, on which character to push, maybe three stacks for the three types.. etc)

So at the end, you just check if `YourStackName.Empty()` and if it is, then hurah it was balanced!